# DynamoDB Scan doesn't seem to recognise my List<Dictionary<string,int>>

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, dynamodb-queries

I'm struggling with DynamoDB AWS from which I'm trying to read some values.

My DynamoDB has this kind of information:

```
{
  "client_sub": "85c1593f-f314-4045-8203-d32b385c8fe4",
  "PlayerCollection": {
    "cube_id": {
      "collection_id_lvl": 5,
      "collection_souls": 20
    },
    "sphere_id": {
      "collection_id_lvl": 5,
      "collection_souls": 20
    }
  }
}
```

In My C# Class i'm trying to read this.. as :

```
[DynamoDBHashKey]
public string client_sub { get; set; }

[DynamoDBProperty(AttributeName = "PlayerCollection")]
public List<Dictionary<string,int>> PlayerCollection { get; set; }
```

When i read my DynamoDB Result,

I find my client_sub : 85c1593f-f314-4045-8203-d32b385c8fe4 => It's OK

But my PlayerCollection count 0, instead of 2 "cuby_id" and "sphere_id" => It's Not Ok

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.

It's not a

```
public List<Dictionary<string,int>> PlayerCollection { get; set; }
```

It's :

```
public Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,int>> PlayerCollection { get; set; }
```